# calculate overlap between two strings in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, optimization, data-structures

I want to write a function that take a two string as input and return the overlap between them. For example : S1="ABCD" and S2= "CDBA" the function should return the overlap= 2 because suffix of first string and prefix of the second one is similar by 2 char "CD" i write this code:

```
public class JavaStringArrayTests {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JavaStringArrayTests jj= new JavaStringArrayTests();
        System.out.print(jj.overlap());
    }

    int overlap() {
        String f1 = "ABCD";
        String f2 = "DBCA";
        int max=0;
        char[] first= f1.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char[] second= f2.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            for (int i2=i; i2<4; i2++) {
                for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
                    if (first[i]==second[j] )
                        max++;
                    else break;
                }
                if (max==0)
                    break;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

this code is work with strings without repetition but when i put For example : S1="ATTC" and S2= "TTCA" it doesn't work is there any ideas to calculate this ? Thanks

Comment: how many char must match to said that is an overlap, 2, higher ?

Comment: You don't need 3 nested loops for this... just 2 should suffice (for a basic approach).

Comment: Are you trying to find the chars that are the same for the same index on the different String? Say `ABCDE` and `XXCXXE` should return 2?

Comment: Sounds like you want the [longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem).

Comment: It should be work with suffix tree maybe. It is a little hard for implementation. Suffix arrays works very similarly and it is simple to implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 3 for loop use only 2 and assign and check the value of j based on max and i respectively.

Note: Produce result as "0" if both the strings are equal

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    for(int j=max; j<i; j++){
        if (first[i]==second[j] ){
            max++;
            break;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this code is work for me anyway i can ignore the case when both are exactly the same because i don't need it in my code

Comment: I don't think this works.  Try the test case of  String s1 = "ABCD"; String s2 = "ABYX";

Comment: It returns the output as "0" which means no overlap. Working as expected.

Comment: Ah I see, the OP is looking for the trailing chars of S1 to match the leading chars of S2.  I interpreted the question incorrectly.

Comment: Returns `2` for `ABCD & BCAD`. 

To fix it you'll need to add `max=0` as follows:
`else {
    max = 0;
    break;
}`

Also there should be included cases in which `s1.contains(s2)` and `s1.equals(s2)`.

Answer (score -1):

You just need two sliding windows into your data strings.  By adjusting the width of the window, you determine the overlap.

```
/**
 * @author aupanner
 */
public class Overlap {

    static int calculateOverlap(final String s1, final String s2) {
        final int s1len = s1.length();
        final int s2len = s2.length();
        final int maxlen = Integer.min(s1len, s2len);

        // from the longest overlap to the shortest possible.
        for (int len = maxlen; len > 0; len--) {
            // sliding window into s1 from 0
            for (int toffset = 0; toffset + len <= s1len; toffset++) {
                // sliding window into s2 from 0
                for (int ooffset = 0; ooffset + len <= s2len; ooffset++) {
                    //System.out.println("Comparing s1.regionMatches(" + toffset + ", s2, " + ooffset + ", " + len + ")");
                    if (s1.regionMatches(toffset, s2, ooffset, len)) {
                        return len;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // no overlap found.
        return 0;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "ABCD";
        String s2 = "DBCA";
        System.out.println("Maximum overlap is: " + calculateOverlap(s1, s2));
        String f1 = "ATTC";
        String f2 = "TTCA";
        System.out.println("Maximum overlap is: " + calculateOverlap(f1, f2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is perfect and it works even when both strings are equal thanks

Comment: 1) This is calculating the longest common substring.  2) This algorithm scales terribly as string lengths increase, particularly in the case of short/non-existing overlaps.

Comment: maximum string will be of length 4 so i think it will work fine